# can not add woocommerce order filter by vendors

Tags: woocommerce, filter, orders, vendor

woocommerce order page in, I want to filter orders by vendor. I am using the wcfm marketplace plugin.
Vendor name appears here. but when I filter, the orders are not listed.

please help :([woocommerce order page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bax3w.jpg)

Comment: Ca you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of wht you have tried so we have a better idea of how to help you

Comment: thank you... but, I need a new code snippet

Comment: So you're expecting someone to fix the issue without knowing what you are doing? I don't think anyone has the time to code this for you

Comment: You're right. I found a code like this, but I need to make this code compatible for wcfm plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```html
function wcmp_admin_filter_by_vendor() {
    global $typenow;
    if ($typenow == 'shop_order') {
        $admin_dd_html = '<select name="admin_order_vendor" id="dropdown_admin_order_vendor"><option value="">'.__("Show All Vendors", "dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor").'</option>';
       $vendors = get_wcmp_vendors();
       if($vendors) :
           foreach ($vendors as $vendor) {
               $admin_dd_html .= '<option value="'.$vendor->term_id.'">'.$vendor->page_title.'</option>';
           }
       endif;
       $admin_dd_html .= '</select>';
       echo $admin_dd_html;
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wcmp_admin_filter_by_vendor');
function get_vendor_parent_order($id) {
    $vendor_orders = get_posts( array(
                                    'numberposts' => -1,
                                    'meta_key'    => '_vendor_id',
                                    'meta_value'  => $id,
                                    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
                                    'post_status' => 'any',
                            ) );
    foreach( $vendor_orders as $vendor_order ) {
        $parent_order = wp_get_post_parent_id( $vendor_order->ID );
        $parent_orders[] = $parent_order;
    }
    return $parent_orders;
}
function filter_orders_by_vendor_in_admin_dashboard( $query ) {
    if (current_user_can('administrator') && !empty($_REQUEST['admin_order_vendor'])) {
        $vendor_term_id = isset($_GET['admin_order_vendor'])?$_GET['admin_order_vendor']:'';
        $vendor =  get_wcmp_vendor_by_term($vendor_term_id);
        $parent_orders = get_vendor_parent_order($vendor->id);
        $query['post__in'] = $parent_orders;
       return $query;
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'wcmp_shop_order_query_request', 'filter_orders_by_vendor_in_admin_dashboard');
function remove_wcmp_order_hook() {
    global $WCMp;
    remove_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', array($WCMp->order, 'wcmp_show_shop_order_columns'), 99, 2 );
}
add_action('init', 'remove_wcmp_order_hook');
function wcmp_show_shop_order_columns($column, $post_id) {
    global $WCMp;
    switch ($column) {
           case 'wcmp_suborder' :
               $wcmp_suborders = $WCMp->order->get_suborders($post_id);
               if ($wcmp_suborders) {
                   echo '<ul class="wcmp-order-vendor" style="margin:0px;">';
                   foreach ($wcmp_suborders as $suborder) {
                       $vendor = get_wcmp_vendor(get_post_field('post_author', $suborder->get_id()));
                       $vendor->ID = get_post_field('post_author', $suborder->get_id());
                       $vendor_term_id = isset($_GET['admin_order_vendor'])?$_GET['admin_order_vendor']:'';
                          $filter_vendor =  get_wcmp_vendor_by_term($vendor_term_id);
                          $filter_vendor_id = isset($filter_vendor->id)?$filter_vendor->id:'';
                        if( $vendor->ID == $filter_vendor_id || $filter_vendor_id == '' ) {
                            $order_uri = apply_filters('wcmp_admin_vendor_shop_order_edit_url', esc_url('post.php?post=' . $suborder->get_id() . '&action=edit'), $suborder->get_id());
                            printf('<li><mark class="%s tips" data-tip="%s">%s</mark> <strong><a href="%s">#%s</a></strong> &ndash; <small class="wcmp-order-for-vendor">%s %s</small></li>', sanitize_title($suborder->get_status()), $suborder->get_status(), $suborder->get_status(), $order_uri, $suborder->get_order_number(), _x('for', 'Order table details', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'), $vendor->page_title
                            );
                        }
                            do_action('wcmp_after_suborder_details', $suborder);
                   }
                   echo '<ul>';
               } else {
                   echo '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
               }
               break;
       }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wcmp_show_shop_order_columns', 99, 2);
```

Comment: . I found a code like this, but I need to make this code compatible for wcfm plugin.